# Packet capture inside windows docker container

Tags: docker, tcp, packet-capture, windows-container

Is it possible to capture tcp packets inside a windows docker container? (using an image ultimately based on microsoft/windowsservercore)

`netsh trace start` fails with `The inbox capture driver could not be started (error=0x800106d9)`

`New-NetEventSession -CaptureMode SaveToFile -Name cat -LocalFilePath c:\cat.etl` fails with `A general error occurred that is not covered by a more specific error code`

(context - I'm trying to debug a networking issue, whereby a dockerised application seems to stop receiving data over an established connection after a period of time. I can run a trace on the docker host and see data getting forwarded to the container; I'd like to be able to do the same from within the container to see if it shows up there, too)

Comment: You sure you are not running into this https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34355

Comment: @GregorySuvalian I don't think so - my issue is with an existing tcp connection that stops working after a while (interesting link though - wasn't aware of that)

Comment: Did you find any way to fix this? I also tried installing nmap, winpcap and all of them but nothing seems to be working!

Comment: @RoozbehG, Did you find any way to fix this?